# Weird Texture stretching

Tags: texturing

[image][image][image]

I have this weird texture stretching on the top of the barrel, how can I fix it. I tried box projection, didn't change anything. I have subdivision modifier active. Thanks

Comment: please share the UV map screenshot of the object

Comment: This is actually without making any seams,default UV I think, I tried adding some, it showed different results but none of them was actually correct. So I assume I am not doing something right. Thanks!

Comment: In UV editor try "Average Island Scale" and then "Pack Islands".

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady didn't help, tried but same problem still ocurs. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

overlapping edges made that error.

[image]

Try selecting it and scale it down.

you can use the uv sync selection as your help in selection.

[image]

also try to change your seam to a better suited position.
[image]

Comment: It is, but actualy there is three overlapping edges, and even some more vertices.I don't know how I managed to do it but I can't fix it right. Even if I scale them all, of 2 of them or just one. Maybe going over again this top part is best idea.

Comment: if it's too complex just add a seam in the problematic area and unwrap it again

Comment: That helped, still no 100% accurate but it will not be seen from very close distance so it will manage. Thanks!

Comment: np. updated the answer for a suggestion on uv seam.

Answer (score 4):

When you are modeling a 3d object you need to study it.
How a wooden barrel built?

check this out:
[image]

A wooden barrel is made from a set of wooden boards (with a concave shape) disposed in a circular way to create the external structure.

The head is just a cylinder put on the top of the barrel. It's another material and another piece.

[image]

So I suggest to rethink your object starting from different 3d shapes. The textures will follow easily when you'll have better parts. Check this shapes:

[image]

Comment: Very nice suggestion for future 3d models and workflow, seems complicated, but probably worth a try. Thanks for advices!

Comment: While a nice overview this in no way addresses the actual problem at hand ergo not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the center vert/loop on top and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> to *Select More* until you've grabbed the necessary loops and then try adjusting your UVs.